# Angular router .otherwise cannot resolve route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this otherwise method:

```
.otherwise(function ($injector) {
     var url = $injector.get("$window").location.href,
         $state = $injector.get("$state"),
         queryStringFromURL = url.substring(url.indexOf("?"));

     $state.go("/products", {queryString: queryStringFromURL});
});
```

When I initially load the page it hits the otherwise, but the page does not load and I get this error in the console:

```
Error: Could not resolve '/products' from state ''
```

I have also tried:

```
.otherwise(function ($injector) {
     var url = $injector.get("$window").location.href,
         $state = $injector.get("$state"),
         queryStringFromURL = url.substring(url.indexOf("?"));

    return "/products" + queryStringFromURL;
});
```

But here the query string is not removed from the url, where previously optional parameters used were stripped from the url after page load.

I am looking to either fix the first solution above, or find a way to pass queryStringFromURL as a parameter in the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the forward-slash.

`$state.go("products", {queryString: queryStringFromURL})`

From the docs:

> `$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])`
>
> `to` : String Absolute State Name or Relative State Path

More here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options